How to use NPOI to read VBA
I have a need to scan many VBA projects on a server. Not using COM.
Is it possble to actually get at the macro code as text, not just the entire project as a Blob.
The file VBA format is documented in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_file_formats/ms-ovba/575462ba-bf67-4190-9fac-c275523c75fc But it is rather obtuse!
